# Jquery variable value doesn't work outside the function

Tags: jquery, onclick

I'm pretty new to jquery and i'm finding difficulty on this issue.

I have a variable "veh_select_prev" defined. Depending upon the click a user makes between the first 2 inner functions it should pass the value to the third inner function. Here is my try:

```
<script>
    var jqOld = jQuery.noConflict();
    jqOld(document).ready(function() {
            var veh_select_prev;

            jqOld("#package_front_suv").click(function(){
            var veh_select_prev = ".cust_suv";
                if(!jqOld("input:checkbox[name='package_type[]']").is(":checked")){
                    alert('Please select at least 1 package');
                }
                else{
                    jqOld(veh_select_prev).hide( "slide", 
                                 { direction: "left"  }, 500 );
                    jqOld(".cust_target4").show( "slide", 
                                  {direction: "right" }, 500 );
                }
            });

            jqOld("#package_front_hatch").click(function(){
            var veh_select_prev = ".cust_hatchback";
                if(!jqOld("input:checkbox[name='package_type[]']").is(":checked")){
                    alert('Please select at least 1 package');
                }
                else{
                    jqOld(veh_select_prev).hide( "slide", 
                                 { direction: "left"  }, 500 );
                    jqOld(".cust_target4").show( "slide", 
                                  {direction: "right" }, 500 );
                }
            });

            jqOld("#order_back").click(function(){
                jqOld(".cust_target4").hide( "slide", 
                             { direction: "right"  }, 500 );
                jqOld(veh_select_prev).show( "slide", 
                              {direction: "left" }, 500 );
            });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: why are you defining variable multiple times  var veh_select_prev;

Comment: Hi Rakesh, as you can see i have assigned different values on each function for that variable. Depending upon the click (first or second function) i want the value to be passed onto the final function i.e, under #order_back.

Comment: in click event remove var

Comment: @user2672112 inside each click event instead of var veh_select_prev = ".cust_hatchback"; assign only veh_select_prev = ".cust_hatchback";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every click event change variable from:

```
var veh_select_prev = "value";
```

To

```
veh_select_prev = "value";
```

Answer (score 1):

Because if u declare a variable inside function using var keyword so it`s mean it`s a locally declared and local variable u can access only inside function, but if u declare a variable inside function without using var keyword it`s mean it`s globally defined variable inside function and global variable you can access everywhere and you don`t need to re-declare again and again..

so use like that -- veh_select_prev = "value";